# Getting started web dev: cshtml results in logic in views

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, razor

Is cshtml or aspx a bad practice in general because it opens the door to write logic in your view pages? wouldn't a pure HTML solution be better where you request server side logic via Ajax/Jquery directly to a webservice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is cshtml or aspx a bad practice in general because it opens the door to write logic in your view pages?*

Yes, In MVC world models are populated with data(after business logic being applied) and these models then binded to View, very less scope to write logic inside view. also it is not good practice because no separation/ reusablity scope.

*wouldn't a pure HTML solution be better where you request server side logic via Ajax/Jquery?*

Yes. And that is the reason today most of the websites are mixed (ajax an server), based to give better UI experience.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong in writing view logic in your views. That's what they are designed for. With a pure HTML solution you wouldn't be able to build dynamic sites.